# Merging Hillshades in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, hillshade

I have nine hillshades generated from DEMs and I was wondering if there is a way to merge all of them into a single layer. I tried using the Merge function but it didn't allow me select all the nine layers at once.

Is there any possibility of achieving this?

I am using ArcGIS Desktop 10.3.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour](https://gis.stackexchange.com/tour). Please do do not add "Thanks" comments; as stated in the [Help Center](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers), "**Please do not add a comment on your question or on an answer to say 'Thank you'.** ... If you want to say 'thank you,' vote on or accept that person's answer, or simply pay it forward by providing a great answer to someone else's question."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [Mosaic To New Raster](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/mosaic-to-new-raster.htm) to merge all the raster images together. However, I am afraid that you may need to mosaic the DEMs first because each image has different min/max range, and when you create a hillshade image based on individual images, that min/max values of each image will be converted to values that range from 0-255, which will create inconsistency in the elevation with the neighboring image. But mosaic the DEM images first will avoid the differences in elevation.

Comment: Thank you, I tried to mosaic the DEMs but the result didn't come out right. However, I mosaicked the Hillshades instead and the result was perfect. Thank you so much!